# Обобщающие слова при однородных членах

Tags: пунктуация

Есть следующее предложение:

Стандарты, применяемые в России и за рубежом, — системы мер, диапазоны давлений, требования к обеспечению безопасности, к температурным режимам, стандарты резьб и т.п. зачастую значительно отличаются друг от друга.

Мне кажется, нужно так:

Стандарты, применяемые в России и за рубежом: системы мер, диапазоны давлений, требования к обеспечению безопасности, к температурным режимам, стандарты резьб и т.п., — зачастую значительно отличаются друг от друга.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможны два варианта:

(1)Стандарты, применяемые в России и за рубежом, — системы мер, диапазоны давлений, требования к обеспечению безопасности, к температурным режимам, стандарты резьб и т.п. — зачастую значительно отличаются друг от друга.

(2)Стандарты, применяемые в России и за рубежом: системы мер, диапазоны давлений, требования к обеспечению безопасности, к температурным режимам, стандарты резьб и т.п.— зачастую значительно отличаются друг от друга.

Сравнить: Все, что могло приглушить звуки, – ковры, портьеры и мягкую мебель – Григ давно убрал из дома.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

При решении нужно "убрать" обособленный оборот, тогда мы получаем два варианта оформления предложения с обобщающим словом: два тире или двоеточие и тире.

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо. Но Вы не поставили запятую после и т.п., а ведь надо закрыть причастный оборот "применяемые в России и за рубежом"?

Comment: Я считаю, что обособленный оборот не включает однородные члены: "Стандарты — системы мер, диапазоны давлений, требования к обеспечению безопасности, к температурным режимам, стандарты резьб и т.п. — зачастую значительно отличаются друг от друга".

Comment: Не очень Вас понимаю. Ведь в 1-м варианте Вы поставили запятую, а во 2-м почему-то нет.

Comment: Второй вариант без оборота; "Стандарты: системы мер, диапазоны давлений, требования к обеспечению безопасности, к температурным режимам, стандарты резьб и т.п. — зачастую значительно отличаются друг от друга". Добавляем оборот, ставится первая запятая, а вторая запятая поглощается двоеточием.

Comment: Все же я не очень уверена насчет поглощения двоеточием. А не могли бы вы скинуть ссылку на правило? потому что вот то, что я нашла в интернете и. кажется, двоеточием тут ничего не поглощается... (см. примечание)
http://pravopisanie_i_stilistika.academic.ru/90/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85

Comment: Но в приведенных примерах дается пояснение, откуда берется запятая. В первом случае запятая перед присоединительным оборотом, во втором случае запятая закрывает  оборот с предлогом "наряду с", в который входит однородный ряд . В нашем случае никаких осложнение нет: простое предложение с однородными членами и обобщающим словом, при этом обобщающее слово распространено определительным оборотом.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, знаки препинания расставлены Вами безупречно!

Comment: Спасибо. А допускается ли первоначальный вариант? Ведь тоже вроде выглядит нормально.

Comment: Безупречно пояснение Софии:

 " При решении нужно "убрать" обособленный оборот, тогда мы получаем два варианта оформления предложения с обобщающим словом: два тире или двоеточие и тире."

 Все понятно и строго по правилам.